# Sending out Ping Requests

Tags: c++, winpcap, icmp

Using WinpCap and trying to generate my own ping requests.

On both machines I see the ping request and the only differences between the ones I've generated the ones Windows has generated is my checksum is 0 (been told that's ok) and the identified is 100 instead of an ever increasing value like Windows uses. (I increase each time I try to send a ping request).

Should I paste the hex dump here? :P

EDIT:
I guess my question here is to find out what could cause Windows to NOT respond to ping requests that show up as valid in Wireshark.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should probably paste the hex dump here.

It could be the fact that the checksum is wrong. Unlike UDP, I believe ICMP (ping) checksum is not optional and should be correct. This is also what I got from [RFC 792](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc792.html).

If you want to use WinPcap with .NET, you can use [Pcap.Net](http://pcapdotnet.codeplex.com), which will allow you to create and send any ICMP packet by writing very few lines of code.

Comment: UDP has a checksum in the header so it doesn't need to be in the payload. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol#Packet_structure